# Primefaces : Select Check Box menu : NullPointerException

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have an implementation of selectCheckBoxMenu in my project. Part of code from my xhtml file is :-

```xml
<p:row >
    <p:column style=" width: 497px; text-align: right;">
        <h:outputText for="toMails" value="To : " />  
    </p:column>
    <p:column style=" width: 497px; text-align: left;">
        <p:selectCheckboxMenu id="toMails" value="#{schedule.selectedEmailIds}" label="Mail Recipients" filter="true" 
            filterText="Filter" filterMatchMode="startsWith" panelStyle="width:220px">  
            <f:selectItems value="#{schedule.users}" />  
        </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
    </p:column>
</p:row>
```

My Bean Class has the code:-

```java
private String[] selectedEmailIds;  

private Map<String,String> users; 

//Getters and Setters

//Value Loader Method
public void loadWorkFlowServices()
{
    try
    {           
        Map<String, String> tmpUsers = new HashMap<String, String>();  
        tmpUsers.put("Scarface", "Scarface");  
        tmpUsers.put("Goodfellas", "Goodfellas");  
        tmpUsers.put("Godfather", "Godfather");  
        tmpUsers.put("Carlito's Way", "Carlito's Way"); 
        tmpUsers.put("Rang De Basanti", "Rang De Basanti"); 
        tmpUsers.put("Despicable Me", "Despicable Me"); 
        tmpUsers.put("The Dark Knight", "The Dark Knight"); 
        setUsers(tmpUsers);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LOGGER.error("Error while loading the workflow services.", e);
    }
}
```

When I select any value from drop down and submit it. I am getting exception -

```
Error occurred while doing security check on URL hit
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.primefaces.component.selectcheckboxmenu.SelectCheckboxMenu.queueEvent(SelectCheckboxMenu.java:199)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:976)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1233)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:698)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
```

I can't find much help online. Please suggest what I am missing.

Comment: Where you call `loadWorkFlowServices()` method?In Constructor ?

Comment: This method is under @PostConstruct, so it gets loaded as page loads.

Comment: You're affecting a `Map<String,String>` to a `String[]`, shouldn't they have the same type ?

Comment: @Omar, the map is the combination of key-value pairs. `selectedEmailIds` is the selected key collection, so in this case it's well done (at least this part).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through your error, I've been browsing Primefaces' `SelectCheckboxMenu` class and found this piece of code (Primefaces 3.5 `SelectCheckboxMenu:199`):

```java
if(event instanceof AjaxBehaviorEvent && eventName.equals("toggleSelect"))
```

Here your `eventName` resolves to `null` for some reason and you get a [NPE](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/nullpointerexception/info). It seems to be related with this [Primefaces bug](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=5123).

Anyway, your provided code works like a charm in 4.0 version, so you should consider an upgrade if you can.

Comment: If this is the case, is there any alternative approach for this in 3.5 because for the moment, there are some restrictions to upgrade. Thanks.

Comment: According to the bug track, it wasn't happening at 3.4.2 version. You can downgrade to it or maybe go through 3.5.x minor versions, which you'll need a license to obtain.